# MSVC2008 C++ placement new for built-in types

Tags: c++, placement-new

I am using MSVC2008 and writing something like this (the exact code is different but this is just to illustrate the question) :

```
void *p = NULL;
int size = 12;
...
...
p = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
if(p != NULL)
{
    new ((int *)p) int[size];
}
...
((int*)p)[5] = 3;
```

to which I get the following compilation error:

```
error C2660: function 'operator new' does not take 2 arguments
```

Now, this works perfectly when I am using my own classes with overloaded placement new that I wrote. However with built-in standard types it does not?
Or am I missing something?

P.S. I am doing things this way because I have to and I know there are alternatives, so please bear with me.

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Try to compile this exact code instead of your original code and see if the error message still appears. If not, your example is flawed.

Comment: Do you overload the global `operator new` function? Then you need to add a second argument for the "placement" parameter.

Comment: Did you include `<new>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, ameyCU...
it was missing

```
#include <new>
```

compiles fine now :)

Comment: C++ haven't had any standard header files with a `.h` suffix since it became standardized in 1998.